# Hierarchical Bayes Normal-Normal Model

Tags: r, self-study

I have the following data for 8 runners in a 100 meter dash:

```
runner 1 88 91 87 82
runner 2 81 85 78 91
runner 3 75 77 83 81
runner 4 92 89 84 82
runner 5 78 79 84 92
runner 6 89 75 79 83
runner 7 91 89 92 91
runner 8 87 86 88 91
```

The ratings represent a performance rating and are normally distributed with unknown mean and unknown variance. Each runner can be considered as a sub-group with a mean and variance.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @Louise, but we treat them differently (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Please tell us what you understand & have tried already, & we'll provide some hints to help get you unstuck. In addition, you are going to need to tell us what the point of this question is.

Comment: Runners 1-8 are entered in a race and I have speed ratings for these runners (last four races in the example... as described in tullyrunners.com). I would like to use Hierarchal Bayes approach to infer group mean and variance and individual runner's mean and variance. I'm learning R at present and would appreciate any help in that area. I am new at this and learning on my own, so be gentle.

Comment: @louise - you need to add detail to your question.  For example, are you able to write out the structure of your data as a bayesian model? (eg $y_{ij}\sim\dots$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example here may help: [When making inferences about group means, are credible Intervals sensitive to within-subject variance while confidence intervals are not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72573/when-making-inferences-about-group-means-are-credible-intervals-sensitive-to-wi?lq=1)

I modified the model slightly for your data. Note that with such little data your results will be heavily dependent on the priors you use so I would attempt modifying the priors on the group means and precisions (1/variance) and seeing the different results to learn.

Here are the results I got:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is modified from John Krushke's example here:
http://psy2.ucsd.edu/~dhuber/cr_SimpleLinearRegressionRepeatedBrugs.R

He has a helpful website and blog:
http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/DoingBayesianDataAnalysis/

```
#Note. To use rjags you need to first install JAGS from here: 
#http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/

install.packages("rjags") #run first time to install package

require(rjags) #load rjags package


#Format your data
subID<-rep(1:8,each=4)

dat<-rbind(88, 91, 87, 82,
81, 85, 78, 91,
75, 77, 83, 81,
92, 89, 84, 82,
78, 79, 84, 92,
89, 75, 79, 83,
91, 89, 92, 91,
87, 86, 88, 91
)

dat<-cbind(subID,dat)
colnames(dat)<-c("Subject","Value")
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)



#Jags fit function
jags.fit<-function(dat){

  #Create JAGS model
  modelstring = "

  model{
  for(n in 1:Ndata){
  y[n]~dnorm(mu[subj[n]],tau[subj[n]]) T(0, )
  }

  for(s in 1:Nsubj){
  mu[s]~dnorm(muG,tauG) T(0, )
  tau[s] ~ dgamma(5,5)
  }


  muG~dnorm(80,.01) T(0, )
  tauG~dgamma(1,1)

  }
  "
  writeLines(modelstring,con="model.txt")

#############  

  #Format Data
  Ndata = nrow(dat)
  subj = as.integer( factor( dat$Subject ,
                                 levels=unique(dat$Subject ) ) )
  Nsubj = length(unique(subj))
  y = as.numeric(dat$Value)

  dataList = list(
    Ndata = Ndata ,
    Nsubj = Nsubj ,
    subj = subj ,
    y = y
  )

  #Nodes to monitor
  parameters=c("muG","tauG","mu","tau")


  #MCMC Settings
  adaptSteps = 1000             
  burnInSteps = 1000            
  nChains = 1                   
  numSavedSteps= nChains*10000          
  thinSteps=20                      
  nPerChain = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains )            


  #Create Model
  jagsModel = jags.model( "model.txt" , data=dataList, 
                          n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps , quiet=FALSE )
  # Burn-in:
  cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
  update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )

  # Getting DIC data:
  load.module("dic")


  # The saved MCMC chain:
  cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
  codaSamples = coda.samples( jagsModel , variable.names=parameters , 
                              n.iter=nPerChain , thin=thinSteps )  

  mcmcChain = as.matrix( codaSamples )

  result = list(codaSamples=codaSamples, mcmcChain=mcmcChain)

}


output<-jags.fit(dat) # fit the model to your data



###make plots
##Overall plots
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
#Plot overall means
hist(output$mcmcChain[,"muG"],col="Grey", freq=F,
main="Overall Mean", xlab="Performance"
)
#Plot overall variance
hist(1/output$mcmcChain[,"tauG"],col="Grey", freq=F,
main="Overall Variance", xlab="Performance")


##Indidvidual Mean Plots
dev.new()
par(mfrow=c(2,4))
for(i in 1:8){
hist(output$mcmcChain[,paste("mu[",i,"]",sep="")],
main=paste("Mean of Runner", i), xlab="Performance", freq=F, col="Grey"
)
}


##Indidvidual Variance Plots
dev.new()
par(mfrow=c(2,4))
for(i in 1:8){
hist(1/output$mcmcChain[,paste("tau[",i,"]",sep="")],
main=paste("Variance of Runner", i), xlab="Performance", freq=F, col="Grey"
)
}

# see what is in the output
attributes(output$mcmcChain)
```

**Edit:**
To see the percent of time the model predicts each runner will win we can take the mean and variance estimated for each individual at each mcmc step, then sample a performance from a distribution determined by those parameters. We can then simply count the number of times each runner had the highest performance.

[image]

```
nSamps<-length(output$mcmcChain[,paste("mu[",i,"]",sep="")])
out=matrix(nrow=nSamps*8,ncol=3)
cnt<-1
for(j in 1:nSamps){
for(i in 1:8){
m<-output$mcmcChain[,paste("mu[",i,"]",sep="")][j]
v<-1/output$mcmcChain[,paste("tau[",i,"]",sep="")][j]
t<-rnorm(1,m,sqrt(v))
out[cnt,]<-cbind(j,i,t)
cnt<-cnt+1
}
}
colnames(out)<-c("N","RunnerID","Time")


winners=matrix(nrow=nSamps,ncol=1)
for(i in 1:nSamps){
sub<-out[which(out[,"N"]==i),]
winners[i]<-sub[which(sub[,"Time"]==max(sub[,"Time"])),"RunnerID"]
}

dev.new()
barplot(100*table(winners)/nSamps, xlab="Runner ID", ylab="% of Wins")
```

Comment: Flask, thank you. You have provided the right directions. There's a lot to digest. I downloaded JAGS and I am attempting to duplicate your results. However, I get the following error in R: Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: Failed to locate any version of JAGS version 3

The rjags package is just an interface to the JAGS library
Make sure you have installed JAGS-3.0.0.exe or higher from
http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files
I can see the JAGS folder in Program Files. I downloaded JAGS-3.4.0.exe. Any suggestions?

Comment: No idea, it may depend on operating system. I am using JAGS-3.2.0 and it is in "program files" using win7. You may try uninstalling and using a the older version of JAGS or asking about this problem as a new question.

Comment: @Louise did you get it working? I am interested to know what the fix turned out to be in case I have this problem in the future.

Comment: I have various versions of JAGS without success (I have w2k). Since I am only interested in this particular problem is there any specific R code that I can use instead of a JAGS model?

Comment: @Louise I only have experience with rJAGS unfortunately. You can try asking [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610036/). Martyn Plummer is the one who created JAGS and he appears to be active on that forum.

Comment: Flask, is it possible to add some r code to determine a winner based on inferences for each runner... highest performance wins (possibly a Monte Carlo simulation). This would be helpful. rJags is not compatible with w2k. I will borrow a system to implement your code. Thanks

Comment: @Louise See the edit. Also, I really want to stress how much these results depend on the prior distributions chosen. Model specification is hugely important here.

Comment: Flask, thanks for all your help. You have been more than generous with your time. You have actually inspired me to learn more about R  and MCMC. Once again thank you.

Comment: @Louise No problem, I am just trying to pay it forward. This site has been a great help to me.